# Performance difference of making class object then calling function vs using static function with scope resolution operator

Tags: c++, c++14

Is there a performance difference (memory and speed both being considered no matter how big or small) if you do this:

```
ClassA a;
a.functionb();
```

vs this:

```
ClassA::functionb();
```

Comment: That depends on the class, the function, the compiler, and your particular compilation options. And possibly other things, like where you do it, as well.

Comment: what about the class and the function?

Comment: What do you mean "what about them"? It depends on what exactly they are and what exactly they do and where exactly they do it.

Comment: @molbdnilo I am not so sure, as functionb is static it does not use state and the compiler can optimize differences away. Likely there is no difference.

Comment: If the class' constructor has observable results, an explicit construction and destruction of the class must happen. If the compiler can prove that not instantiating a class does not result in any observable effects, the compiler can, but is not obligated to, optimize it away.

Comment: You are right. That is a catch.

Comment: Why would you ever do the former, if you can do the latter? But in that case, does it even need to be a member function at all? Can't it be free? Overall, too vague/broad/opinionated without further context.

Comment: to decide whether a method should be static or not, performance would be my least concern. Not because performance does not matter, but because the two variants are not doing the same, hence imho comparing their performance is questionable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how expensive it is to create an object of the class.

If this cheap, there is no difference. [This example](https://godbolt.org/z/zYcaf4) compiles to the very same binary an thus has the same execution speed.

```
class Foo{
    public:
    static int bar() {return 1;}
};

class Foo2{
    public:
    static int bar() {return 1;}
};



int main () {
   //return Foo::bar();
   Foo2 foo ;
   return foo.bar();
}
```

General remarks: If you are concerned about performance, the very frist thing to do is to set up a time measurement and check where your hotspot is. Thsi can be done using a tool such as `perf` or `vTune`. Make sure you use a high optimization level of the compiler (`-O3`).

Comment: but wouldn't the constructor of the Foo::bar() be called each function call? and Foo2 foo would only have 1 constructor call?

Comment: In debug code yes, in optimized code no. Use the link to the compiler Explorer and play around with it. This is why the intuition is almost always wrong

Comment: will do, thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a performance difference

Depends on details. If the program is optimised, and the class is stateless, and if it has no user defined constructor nor destructor, and the instance has automatic storage duration or is a temporary, and there is no indirection involved - i.e. all things being equal - then I don't see a reason why there would be difference in performance.

You can find out if there is significant performance difference in practice by measuring.